# Maven test does not complete

Tags: maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

When i run a 
    mvn test
Maven runs all the tests successfully and then goes on a wait infinite loop
I see a java process in the task manager and  I have to kill it before maven returns with this error message

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:33.949s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 17 14:50:01 EDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
4:test (default-test) on project EDIFileHandling: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to c:\code\target\surefire-reports for the individual test
results.
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

R

`C:\Users\Raghuveer.Rao>jstack 7256
2011-06-17 15:24:55
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing):`

"Thread-2" prio=6 tid=0x03ed3000 nid=0x14d0 waiting for monitor entry [0x04ddf00
0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.close(Unknown Source)
        - waiting to lock <0x23ba76f0> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.SessionManager.closeAllSessions(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x292ce828> (a org.hsqldb.SessionManager)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23b8efe8> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23b90f30> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabase
Configurer.shutdown(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:42)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.
shutdownDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryB
ean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destr
oy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
        - locked <0x2951f1c0> (a java.util.LinkedHashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$3.run(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:940)

"Thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x03ed2c00 nid=0x1fe0 waiting for monitor entry [0x04d8f00
0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.hsqldb.SessionManager.closeAllSessions(Unknown Source)
        - waiting to lock <0x292ce828> (a org.hsqldb.SessionManager)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23ba76f0> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23ba9568> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabase
Configurer.shutdown(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:42)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.
shutdownDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryB
ean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destr
oy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
        - locked <0x2910d510> (a java.util.LinkedHashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$3.run(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:940)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x01bdac00 nid=0x1eb0 runnable [0x000000
00]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01bc8400 nid=0x18e8 waiting on conditi
on [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01bc5400 nid=0x1ac0 waiting on condition
[0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01bc2400 nid=0x1fbc runnable [0x0000000
0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x01bbb800 nid=0x1c00 in Object.wait() [0x03cdf000
]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x290702b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
        - locked <0x290702b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01bba000 nid=0x810 in Object.wait() [0x
03c8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x29070340> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0x29070340> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00e29800 nid=0x1e20 in Object.wait() [0x001bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x294c4300> (a org.springframework.context.support.Abstrac
tApplicationContext$3)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1186)
        - locked <0x294c4300> (a org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApp
licationContext$3)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1239)
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.
java:79)
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.jav
a:24)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:79)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:123)
        at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:168)
        - locked <0x38b53ef8> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:90)
        at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:904)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.j
ava:986)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01b7e400 nid=0x1e10 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01bec800 nid=0x1bac waiting on condition

JNI global references: 1776

## Found one Java-level deadlock:

"Thread-2":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0467c1cc (object 0x23ba76f0, a org.hsqldb.Session),
  which is held by "Thread-1"
"Thread-1":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x01bbf56c (object 0x292ce828, a org.hsqldb.SessionMan
ager),
  which is held by "Thread-2"

## Java stack information for the threads listed above:

"Thread-2":
        at org.hsqldb.Session.close(Unknown Source)
        - waiting to lock <0x23ba76f0> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.SessionManager.closeAllSessions(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x292ce828> (a org.hsqldb.SessionManager)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23b8efe8> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23b90f30> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabase
Configurer.shutdown(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:42)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.
shutdownDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryB
ean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destr
oy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
        - locked <0x2951f1c0> (a java.util.LinkedHashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$3.run(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:940)
"Thread-1":
        at org.hsqldb.SessionManager.closeAllSessions(Unknown Source)
        - waiting to lock <0x292ce828> (a org.hsqldb.SessionManager)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23ba76f0> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23ba9568> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabase
Configurer.shutdown(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:42)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.
shutdownDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryB
ean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destr
oy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
        - locked <0x2910d510> (a java.util.LinkedHashMap)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$3.run(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:940)

Found 1 deadlock.

C:\Users\Raghuveer.Rao>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven surefire plugin by default spawns a new process to run the tests. This is probably the process you are killing. When maven notices its child process was interrupted, it probably assummes that the tests failed.

Have a look at `/target/surefire-reports` for confirmation. What you can do to help us diagnose the problem is to find the surefire process id (the one you are killing) and run:

```
$ jstack ID
```

Stack dump will tell you what is causing the test to hung.

Comment: I see a deadloacked hsqldb process

Comment: I had to move down the version of hsqldb from 2.0 to 1.8.0.10 to solve this issue. Thanks for the help